# Indexing in .children list not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html

Could anyone please explain why for the given HTML

```
<body>
  <div id="ustack1">
  Block 1:
  <div id="0"> 0 </div>
  <div id="1"> 1 </div>
  <div id="2"> 2 </div>
  <div id="3"> 3 </div>
  <div id="4"> 4 </div>
  <div id="5"> 5 </div>
  <div id="6"> 6 </div>
  <div id="7"> 7 </div>
  <div id="8"> 8 </div>
  <div id="9"> 9 </div>
  <div id="10"> 10 </div>
</div>

<div id="stagingDiv" style="display:inline-block;">
  Block 2:
</div>
</body>
```

And the corresponding javascript

```
var cards = document.getElementById("ustack1").children;

for(i=0;i<cards.length;i++){
  document.getElementById("stagingDiv").appendChild(cards[i]);
}
```

(As seen in this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/73oszkj9/ )

that the odd elements are being skipped over?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cards` is a live HTMLCollection.  When you perform the `appendChild`, you're moving the node to another place in the DOM, which removes it from the collection.  One solution is to just iterate over cards until its length is zero:

```
while(cards.length > 0){
    document.getElementById("stagingDiv").appendChild(cards[0]);
}
```

Here's an updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lkvdep52/

If it makes you feel any better, this is a mistake that many of us have made at one time or another ;-)  Using the browser debugger is a good way to understand the underlying cause for problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

When you use pure appendChil you are cutting the exact element from its parent. Add `cloneNode` to make a copy of that elements:

```
var cards = document.getElementById("ustack1").children;
for(i=0;i<cards.length;i++){
  document.getElementById("stagingDiv").appendChild(cards[i].cloneNode(true));
}
```

At the end you can remove children of first parent if needed.